# How to convert this weird string to DateTime format in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have come across this weird data string, and I really don't know what I can do to convert it.

> "Sat Jan 07 03:18:58 +0000 2012"

Does anyone know how to convert it?

Comment: Agreed. It looks like a standard DateTime string, with a GMT (timezone) offset (+0000) component.

Comment: what u tried? your code?

Comment: I try to convert it using DateTime.Parse() , it gives me an invalid format error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [DateTimeOffset.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343428.aspx) method to specify the exact [custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) that the date is in, like below. I'm using [DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) because you have the timezone offset value in the string.

```
string myDateString = "Sat Jan 07 03:18:58 +0000 2012";
string customFormat = "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy";

DateTimeOffset dto = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(myDateString, customFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Then you can use the different properties of the DateTimeOffset structure to work with the date as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dateValue; 
DateTime parsedDate;

string dateString = "Sat Jan 07 03:18:58 +0000 2012";      

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
    {
        dateValue = parsedDate;            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use DateTime.ParseExact:

```
CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US"); 
    string strDate = "Sat Jan 07 03:18:58 +0000 2012";
    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "ddd MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy", enUS, DateTimeStyles.None);
```